# Подключить библиотеку tmhOauth к Kohana

Tags: twitter, php, kohana

Хочу прикрутить твиттеровскую библиотеку [tmhOauth](https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth) к php фреймворку Kohana, у когото будут идеи как это сделать правильно? Куда кинуть саму библиотеку, и нужно ли както дать знать кохане про эту новую библиотеку?

Comment: спасибо Мишань, благодаря тебе познакомился с composer'ом, перенеси в ответ - засчитаю как верный)

Comment: :) приятно видеть, что на этом форуме не всем нужен прямой ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если версия >= 3.3, то для вас там уже есть папочка `vendors`. Загружаете эту библиотеку с помощью `composer`'а и может оно сразу и подхватится. А может надо будет допилить немного - не помню.